# Background image of div zooms in on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with a background image in it. On computer it looks nice but it does zoom in when i go on mobile?

Here are my HTML and CSS codes:

```css
.vh {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    background: url("http://autohof.coersonline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Headerplaat-4.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="vh">
</div>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try `background-size:100%`

Comment: @PrasathV when i do that the image doesnt display on mobile.

Comment: have you set the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch yes, i did.

Comment: what mobile browser are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you might be facing is a known **bug in iOS Safari** with viewport units. Try to avoid using those or using [this plugin](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill) to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The background will be responsive to the height using the following CSS.

```
background-image: url('YOUR_IMAGE');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.vh {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("http://autohof.coersonline.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Headerplaat-4.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vh">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```